# How to let the user know that a new message has arrived?

Tags: angular, firebase

There are two such tables:

table **friends/${id}** with fields **creatorId** and **receiverId**;

table **chat/${chatId}/messages/${id}** with fields **dateTime, message, receiverId, creatorId, username**

How can  let the recipient know about a new message he received from a friend?

Need to create an additional field in the **friends** table or create a new table?

Comment: Which database are you using -  Realtime Database or Firestore?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Firestore